# initWithBase64Encoding deprecated base64

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding

I am receiving a warning in Xcode after upgrading to Xcode 7 in my project, I'm using `CoacoSecurity` which uses `Base64` for encryption in the following line of code :

```
if (![NSData instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithBase64EncodedString:options:)])
{

    decoded = [[self alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])]];

}
```

Its telling me that `initWithBase64Encoding` is deprecated, so how can i get over this warning and fix it.

I've converted it but I'm getting another warning:

```
decoded = [[self alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]" withString:@""] options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
```

The warning says:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type enum NSStringCompareOptions to different enumeration type NSDataBase64DecodingOptions (aka enum NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)
```

Comment: Why don't you go to the documentation of the deprecated method? It tells you what to use.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
```

instand of

```
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64Encoding:(NSString *)dict];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works with OSX 10.8 and up.

```c
// assume sData is an NSString that's already been set
NSData *vData;
if ([vData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
  vData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:sData options:kNilOptions];
} else { // 10.8 or earlier
  vData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:sData];
}
NSString *sResult = [[NSString alloc]
            initWithData:vData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I threw in the `sResult` line only if you wanted to convert it to an NSString instead of an NSData.

So, that gives you a Base64 encoded string. If you want to now unencode it, you would do:

```
// assuming sData is an NSString that's already been set
NSString *sResult = @"";
NSData *vData = [sData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([vData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
    sResult = [vData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
} else { // 10.8 or earlier
    sResult = [vData base64Encoding];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first i used `initWithBase64Encoding` as `@Ske57` recommended and then to get over that warning i had to cast it to `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions` and it should work fine :

```
decoded = [[self alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]" withString:@""] options:(NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)NSRegularExpressionSearch];
```